# how to Rebind Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-grid

Consider I have below mentioned Telrik Grid and first time it is loaded by employee details(name, Description). I want to  add a row in telrik grid when i click add button which is out side of grid. My problem is how to add new record with existing record. I mean how to rebind the grid.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Project.Models.Employee>()
    .Name("myName")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.EmpId))

    .Columns(columns => {            
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(200);            
        columns.Bound(o => o.Description).Width(400);
    })
)
```

Please, provide me better solution. Remember my button out side the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example. This demo explains how to do the editing with the grid using AJAX.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax

Go through the demo - things are pretty clear what to do.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)

Comment: i have added new item in grid. but when i am going to view source page.there i am not able to view my added item. i am refreshing the grid by rebind method

Answer (score 0):

If you in client side, then you can use javascript function  rebind():

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");
//send additional arguments by passing them as a literal JavaScript object
grid.rebind({customerID : "ALFKI"});
```

But for more custom answer i need more information about your scenario. Is it ajax binding, server binding, or else. How do you add row (is it editing in cell or else) etc.

Comment: How you add or edit? Is it popup window, or something else? What event you use to call rebind? If you refresh grid manually, will your new record be in grid

Answer (score 0):

**'It could be helpfull'**

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");
//send additional arguments by passing them as a literal JavaScript object
grid.rebind({customerID : "SAJJAD"});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to the users question. And mostly try to use the users code in providing an answer.